# How to add a hyperlink to the data in the created div using API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I am retrieving data based on users input (zipcode), using API. They get three types of information, name of the institution, address and webpage. I would like to add a hyperlink to the webpage line `(<p>${data[i].website}</p>)` but none of my ideas worked. Thank you, guys.

```
function ajaxCallNY(zipcode){
$.ajax({
    url: "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/72ss-25qh.json?zip_code=" + zipcode,
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      "$limit" : 50,
      "$$app_token" : app_token
    }
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){  
    var nyDiv = $(`<div class="col s12 m6">
                  <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                  <div class="card-content white-text">
                  <span class"card-title">${data[i].agency_id}</span>
                  <p>${data[i].address}</p>
                  <p>${data[i].website}</p>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  `);
      $("#zipcode").append(nyDiv);
  }
});
}
```

Comment: have you tried using  `<a href="${data[i].website}"></a>` ?

Comment: That totally has sense, but it doesn`t work. It doesn`t show anything, the field remains blank.  Thank you though.

Comment: Did you put anything between the hyperlink ? any texts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using template literals already, you can do it like this:

```
`
<div class="col s12 m6">
  <p>${data[i].address}</p>
  <p><a href="${data[i].website}">Link</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
`
```

Comment: Nice! Happy coding! It would help if you accept the answer, thank you!